# Resuming nested for loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

When doing some looping over tables/pixel images in javascript, I'm trying to do it asynchronously, to prevent browser lag.

I'm therefore trying to exit and resume `for` loop when certain number of iterations was performed. It's a nested loop, for `x` and `y` coordinate. This is my concept:

```
//`data` contains info from prewious executions
function asynchronous(data) {
    var x = data.x;
    var y = data.y;
    var max_x = ...;
    var max_y = ...;
    var iterations = 0;
    var max_iterations = 1000;
    for(;y<max_y&&iterations<max_iterations; y++) {
      for(;x<max_x&&iterations<max_iterations; x++) {
        //Do something
        ...
        //Iterate iterations
        iterations++;
      }
    }
    //Print the status
    console.log(...);
    //Save our position for next execution
    data.x = x;
    data.y = y;
}
```

Then, we can call it by some interval, in general like this:

```
var data = {x:0, y:0};
setInterval(function() {asynchronous.apply(data, []);}, 20);
```

For some reason, the variables are not reseting properly and I get infinite loop:

[image: firebug console]

I have class for that:

```
  new ProgressManager(
    function() {
      //x and y from prewious iterations
      var x = this.x;
      var y= this.y;
      //Canvas related stuff
      var array = this.imageData.data;
      var width = this.imageData.width;
      var height = this.imageData.height;
      //step in this progress execution
      var step=0;
      //Iterate through x and y, starting from prewious values
      for (;y < height&&step<1000; y++) {
        //Cache computed y offset
        var ofy = y * width;
        for (;x < width&&step<1000; x++) {
          //Do some canvas operation here

          //Iterate step
          step++;
        }
      }
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.progress+=step;
      return new ProgressEvent(null, null, variables.progress/(width*height),1);
    },
    //Data for the progress
    {x:0,y:0,progress:0,ctx:ctx,imageData:data},
    //onFinish callback
    function() {
      console.log("DONE!");
      this.ctx.putImageData(this.imageData);    
    },
    //onProgress callback
    function(event) {
      document.title=Math.round((event.progress)*1000)/10+"%";
    }
  ).start();
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example. How/where is `asynchronous` called?

Comment: It's unclear how you exit from nested `for` loop

Comment: That does not matter at all. I'll add some code to give you general idea how is it done.

Comment: @hindmost How is it unclear? It exits if the conditions are not met, as any other `for` loop.